# Assigning .on() - keyup to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The idea of this script is to allow dynamically created elements to respond to a keyup function that changes the inner html (or jQuery text()) based on what is inside of a text form.

Each dynamically created element has it's own text form and title. So whatever you type in that given element's text form should become the title for that element which is wrapped in  tags.

I've tried a few ways but I just cant get it to work. What is the best way to go about this?

Here's my latest attempt - http://jsfiddle.net/gnkxxgjz/1/

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.qForms', function() {
    var nameOfLoan = [];

    var loanOfName = function(t) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('.loanNameV'+t)) {
                $('body').on('keyup', '.qForms', function() {
                        var loanN = $('.loanNameV'+t).val();
                        $('.nameLoan'+t).text(loanN);
                });
    }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    for (var t=1; t < z; t++) {
        nameOfLoan[t] = loanOfName(t);
    }

    for (var j=1; j < z; j++) {
        nameOfLoan[j]();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please generate a new fiddle with your latest attempt and explain what is not working about it.

Comment: Please [show some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Perhaps add some HTML context to give us a clearer picture of what you are working with.

Comment: Maybe add some comments to your javascript indicating what you think each line does.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddanone/xy0kvqs3/)

```
<button onclick="crea()">create</button>
<div id="d1">
</div>


function crea(){

    $('#d1').append( $("<h2></h2><input>").on('keyup',function(){
        $(this).prev().html( $(this).val() );
    }) )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
$(document).on("keypress", $("input"), function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).attr("id"))
});
```

This will print to the console the id attribute of any input field you type into. Please provide how the input and text elements are related and I might be able to link them in this code piece.